# New job hasn't confirmed a schedule with me and I need to make plans

Tags: communication, hiring-process, new-job

I have been in contact with a liquor store that is interested in hiring me. There has been some confusion. The manager called and left me a voice mail saying they were interested in hiring me if I'm still available and to give him a call back on his cell. Unfortunately I couldn't hear the number the way he spoke it into the phone. I ended up calling another branch of the same chain and they said he had just left on vacation (this was a day after he left the voice mail). In the voice mail he mentioned that potentially they would start me working next week (which now starts tomorrow), but with him gone and no one being able to answer my question I do not know my schedule. The person I spoke with said he can't be reached on vacation.

This is a problem because I'm trying to schedule my week and have no idea which days or what times I will be working. There is a professional development class I would like to attend but am not sure if it would conflict with work given the time. What are my options? Should I leave my whole week open or should I just start making other arrangements? The liquor store is open 7 days a week from 11am - 11pm.

Also, as glad as I am to have the job, it pays very poorly (most other liquor stores pay almost double for the starting wage). I am still looking for other work and have interviews coming up.

Comment: Doesn't the voicemail service from your phone provider give you the number which was used to call & leave the voicemail? So can't you just redial that?

Comment: @brhans annoyingly mine doesn't

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Places like liquor stores work their employees by shift. If you haven't been given a shift time they are probably not expecting you to show up. I would not cancel any plans you have for the week.

It might still be a good idea to show up when the store opens, but expect to be given some shifts, rather than be put to work immediately. You have a fighting chance to schedule your shifts around your plans for the week.

If you show up, and the manager gives you some shift times, that's the time to start cancelling your week plans.

Answer (score 7):

> Should I leave my whole week open or should I just start making other
>   arrangements? The liquor store is open 7 days a week from 11am - 11pm.

I suppose it depends on how badly you want the job.

If it were me, I'd show up at the store bright and early at 11am. I'd talk to whoever was working, in hopes that they would either know something about your arrival, or know how to get in touch with the manager.

If I cared enough about the job, I'd reschedule my week as necessary.